# Monitor a change in the property of a Telerik ScheduleView control in WPF

Tags: c#, properties, propertychanged

I have 2 properties to a class (WPF control): `HorizontalOffset` and `VerticalOffset` (both public `Double`'s). I would like to call a method whenever these properties change. How can I do this? I know of one way - but I'm pretty sure it's not the right way (using a `DispatcherTimer` of very short tick intervals to monitor the property).

EDIT FOR MORE CONTEXT:

These properties belong to a telerik scheduleview control.

Comment: Use events? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx

Comment: I know how to subscribe to existing events - but I have no experience with creating my own events ready for subscription - is this possible? Is this the way you would say is most efficient for what I want to achieve here?

Comment: Well, given that these are two properties on a type you don't own; you need to see what mechanism, if any, Telerik have exposed on the control for monitoring those properties.  Given it's WPF, I would have thought it's `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  In this case you're not exposing your own event source, you need to hope that one already exists on that control

Comment: I'll have a look into that now then. But assuming there isn't already a way of monitoring these properties changing - is there no other way to observe properties??

Comment: Not really, no.  Certainly using a timer is not the way forward.  Casting an eye over the (slightly sticky, it has to be said) Telerik API docs, the control appears to implement INotifyPropertyChanged; therefore you subscribe to it's `PropertyChanged` event and do something when the args.PropertyName is either `"HorizontalOffset"` or `"VerticalOffset"`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Leverage the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface implementation of the control.

If the control is called `myScheduleView`:

```
//subscribe to the event (usually added via the designer, in fairness)
myScheduleView.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(
  myScheduleView_PropertyChanged);

private void myScheduleView_PropertyChanged(Object sender,
  PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
  if(e.PropertyName == "HorizontalOffset" ||
     e.PropertyName == "VerticalOffset")
  {
    //TODO: something
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

> I know of one way ... `DispatcherTimer`

Wow avoid that :) `INotifyPropertyChange` interface is your friend. See [the msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) for samples.

You basically fire an event(usually called `onPropertyChanged`) on the `Setter` of your properties and the subscribers handle it.

an example implementation from the `msdn` goes:

```
// This is a simple customer class that 
// implements the IPropertyChange interface.
public class DemoCustomer  : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;    
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
          PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));            
    }

    public string CustomerName
    {
        //getter
        set
        {
            if (value != this.customerNameValue)
            {
                this.customerNameValue = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("CustomerName");
            }
        }
    }
}
```